# The 'resolution' argument is incompatible with functions that have side effects

Tags: pine-script

It is giving me an error as -

**The 'resolution' argument is incompatible with functions that have side effects.**

***strategy.entry("Long",strategy.long,1,when=EnterLong)*** - this is the code for which it is giving me an error.

Note: I am not into programming or writing codes. This is my first effort and am seeking help. Please don't mind if this seems too lame or stupid.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to remove the resolution argument from strategy(). If you wish the strategy to make use of a different time frame you'll either have to refactor using security calls, or change the chart timeframe to the desired timeframe for the strategy.

Comment: Thanks. this solved it for me.